# dockerfile pip install -r requirements.txt giving file not found error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, fastapi

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

COPY ./app /app/app

WORKDIR /app/app

RUN "pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

And here's my folder structure:

[image]

When I try to build the image using `docker build -t myimage .`, I get the following error: [image]

Any insight into resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: `docker build` should write out text, not a rather dark PNG file.  Can you replace the image with the text output of the command?

Comment: Remove the quotation marks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
```